# Open Chrome with specific profile from WSL

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, browser, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Im trying to get any urls opened from WSL commands to open with a specific Chrome profile, in this case, specifically for `aws sso login` which triggers a browser login.

If i set the `BROWSER` env var to something like firefox (chrome is default) it will open in firefox

`export BROWSER="/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"`

However if i set it to chrome with a `--profile-directory="profile 2"` it still uses the default profile.

If i just invoke it

`/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 2" google.com`

It will open chrome with the specific profile just fine.
Here is how i've exported it

`export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 2"'`

Perhaps im screwing something up with quoting?

Answer (score 1):

Once adding the params i needed to escape the space so setting it like this worked.

`export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 2"'`

without params, the escape doesnt seem to be needed